# Using global list in recursive SQL query to avoid visted nodes

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query, circular-reference

I have a self-referential table **User**:

```
id          | follower
------------|------------
1 (adam)    | 2 (bob)
1 (adam)    | 3 (charlie)
2 (bob)     | 1 (adam)
2 (bob)     | 3 (charlie)
```

Note that there are circular references.

I want to get all the followers, and followers of the followers, and so on of a user such that all the followers are presented in a flattened list, with their respective depths

For Adam:

```
id | follower    | depth
---|-------------|-------
1  | 1 (bob)     | 0
2  | 3 (charlie) | 0
3  | 1 (adam)    | 1 (bob -> adam)
4  | 3 (charlie) | 1 (bob -> charlie)
```

## Problem

I want to avoid the rows 3 and 4, which represents two problems:

1. `adam -> bob -> adam` because it's circular.
2. `adam -> bob -> charlie` because charlie has already appeared before.

I'm able to solve problem #1 by using the following query by keeping a `path` column of visited `id`s in a branch

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT id, follower, 0 as depth, ARRAY[id] AS path
  FROM user
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, follower, depth + 1, id || path
  FROM user
  JOIN cte ON user.id = cte.follower
  WHERE NOT path @> Array[user.id]
)
SELECT * from cte
```

But it doesn't resolve problem #2.

It gives the following result:

```
follower    | depth | path
------------|-------|-----
2 (bob)     | 0     | {2}
3 (charlie) | 0     | {3}
3 (charlie) | 1     | {2, 3}
```

It still has problem #2 (duplicate `charlie` entry) because `path` column only keeps a list of `id`s in a specific branch.

How do I fix problem #2?

## Possible solution

I can solve it in my code (Node.JS) by keeping a **global** cache (`path` equivalent).

```
const list = {}; /* <-- GLOBAL cache */
function recurse(user, depth = 0) {
  for(const { id, followers } of user.followers) {
    if (!(id in list)) {
      list[id] = {id, depth}
      recurse({ followers }, depth + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Whereas, as far as I can tell, the above SQL query is the equivalent of something like:

```
function recursive() {
  const list = {}; /* <-- LOCAL cache */
  for(const {id} of followers)
    if (!(id in list)) ...
```

How to I replicate my solution in code using a global cache in SQL?

Or any other way I can achieve the desired result?

I'm using Node.JS and PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to select only one row per follower after the recursive search:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
      SELECT id, follower, 0 as depth, ARRAY[id] AS path
      FROM user
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id, follower, depth + 1, id || path
      FROM user
      JOIN cte ON user.id = cte.follower
      WHERE NOT path @> Array[user.id]
     )
SELECT DISTINCT ON (follower) *
FROM cte
ORDER BY follower, depth;
```

Comment: Is there any chance I could do so ***during*** the recursive search itself (using global variable or something)? I know this'd probably work in this case, but my original problem is a bit different, and I though rephrasing it this way might get me a solution. My original problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63226402/using-global-variable-in-recursive-sql-query-to-avoid-circular-references). Basically my query is slow due to the fact that I'm not able to eliminate the desired duplicate entries ***during*** the search query itself - so a solution that does that would be ideal.

Comment: The obvious method would be replacing the recursion with a loop in a Stored Procedure. This way the data can be filtered after each loop.